# Firefox replaces image URL slashes with percent symbol

Tags: php, mysql, image, firefox, hyperlink

I have a strange bug with my work that only appears on Firefox.  On other browsers, image urls are retrieved from a database and successfuly display products alongside their product information, but not on Firefox.  Upon inspecting the differences in generated source code between Google Chrome and Firefox, shows the url being generated being different for Firefox.

Here is the line

```
if (!empty($link))
{echo'<img src = "../'.$link.'" alt="" width="50%" height="60%" />';}
```

When the image generates in Google Chrome, its fine.  But in Firefox, images are broken.  When inspecting the link, it looks like this
http://www.url.com/products%1234567890%Image_For_Items_Record_80.jpg

Firefox is changing the \ slashes into %, why does it do this?  The retrieved string $link from the database is just a string that should be echoed into the image source.  Is there a workaround for Firefox?

Comment: `\\` is not valid in URLs anyway. Firefox just encodes them. You should avoid the backslash completely.

Comment: `$link` is properly set in the database? Also, in your last paragraph, did you really mean `\` (back)slashes instead of `/` (forward) slashes?

Comment: Are all your product imagess in the `products` folder? Why not hard code the `/products/` or does it change?

Answer (score 0):

The comments here are correct.  Some customer software is improperly generating the URLS of the respective items in the database.  A singular link is supposed to automatically generate something along the lines of products/product_number.jpg.  But instead its generating the wrong slash.

The only reason I haven't been having problems in Google Chrome is because Chrome is automatically changing '\' into '/'.  Firefox changes them into '%'. The problem is not with the php but the software converting Quickbooks into a MySQL database.

Comment: You can always do a simple `str_replace` to fix them